# How to decrypt a Joomla User Facebook password?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, encryption, joomla

I've a Joomla app that uses the JLV Facebook Login extension to login to app using a facebook account. The first time that I log in to the app using facebook accout, a user is created in the joomla's users table. Well, I can decrypt a Joomla user password inside that table (Passwords uses MD5 encryption) but when the encrypted password is created by a facebook login, I cannot.

Somebody knows how to decrypt the user password when the user was created by a facebook login?

Thanks!

Comment: The password is stored encrypted, I need decrypt it because I need compare a password received from a webservice against the password stored in database

Comment: Usually, you encrypt the password you want to check with the same methodology and compare the results. Being able to reverse an encrypted password is quite dangerous.

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption, it's cryptographic hashing.  There's a big difference, the main one being that the latter is a one-way operation.  Short of brute force you can't "decrypt" a hash.

Comment: Why would you be using MD5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating the new user, the module generates a random password with length 5, using the function

```
JUserHelper::genRandomPassword(5);
```

and then creates an md5-hash on insertion in the database.

A new random password is generated on each successful facebook login, using the same method. So there is no connection between the facebook password and the hashed password in the joomla database.

Comment: You're right! The facebook id is random and facebook login doesn't use it.